# What's the isomorphism $Ω^{1}(B)\otimes\mathfrak{g}\sim Ω^{1}(B,ad(P))$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, principal-bundles

Let $p:P\rightarrow B$ be a principal $G$-bundle over a smooth manifold $B$. How can I show that
$$Ω^{1}(B)\otimes\mathfrak{g} ≃ Ω^{1}(B,ad(P))$$
where $Ω^{1}(B,ad(P))\equiv\Gamma(\Lambda^{k}(T^{*}B)\otimes ad(P))=Hom(\Lambda^{k}(T^{*}B),ad(P))$?

Here  I used that $ad(P):=P\times_{G}\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: The left-hand side has nothing to do with $P$, so this is the vector space of all $\mathfrak g$-valued $1$-forms on $B$.

Comment: Yeah but there should be a way to prove that the right hand side is isomorphic to the left one, I mean at least that's what's written in my notes

Comment: I think your notes are wrong. There are clear typos in the definition line. It seems that you're looking at tensorial forms on $P$ of type $\text{ad}(P)$ or some such. You'd better clarify with your lecturer.